# Can't implement a recursion search in binary tree

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-tree

Here's my code:

```
  template <typename DataType> bool SearchValue(TreeNode<DataType> *root, DataType search_value)
{
    if(search_value != root->data)
    {
        if(root->right != NULL)
        {
            return SearchValue(root->right, search_value);
        }
        if (root->left != NULL)
        {
            return SearchValue(root->left, search_value);
        }
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I can't make `SearchValue` function work properly. The condition is not to change the signature of `SearchValue` function.
The problem is following: for example we try to find the element with data field equals "90" and it exists in the tree. Sometimes this code finds this element and sometimes not - depending on it's position in the tree.
The question is how to make it work right every time.

I build the tree in such way:

```
template <typename DataType> TreeNode<DataType> *BuildTree()
{
    TreeNode<DataType> *root = new TreeNode<DataType>(10, new TreeNode<DataType>(20), new TreeNode<DataType>(30));

    TreeNode<DataType> *curRoot = root;
    curRoot = curRoot->left;
    curRoot->left = new TreeNode<DataType>(40);
    curRoot->left->left = new TreeNode<DataType>(70);
    curRoot->right = new TreeNode<DataType>(50);
    curRoot = curRoot->right;
    curRoot->left = new TreeNode<DataType>(80, new TreeNode<DataType>(100), new TreeNode<DataType>(110));
    curRoot = root->right;
    curRoot->left = new TreeNode<DataType>(60);
    curRoot = curRoot->left;
    curRoot->right = new TreeNode<DataType>(90, new TreeNode<DataType>(120), new TreeNode<DataType>(130));

    return root;
}
```

I test the search this way:

```
TreeNode<int> *treeRoot = BuildTree<int>();
    int valueToFind = treeRoot->data;
    cout << "Enter the value you'd like to find in the tree: ";
    cin >> valueToFind;
    cin.get();
    if(SearchValue(treeRoot, valueToFind) == true)
    {
        cout << "Value " << valueToFind << " was found!";
    }
```

The way I implement the tree:

```
template <typename DataType> struct TreeNode
{
    TreeNode(DataType val, TreeNode<DataType> *leftPtr = NULL, TreeNode<DataType> *rightPtr = NULL)
    {
        left = leftPtr;
        right = rightPtr;
        data = val;
    }
    TreeNode<DataType> *left, *right;
    DataType data;
};
```

Comment: Can you tell us the problem you've hit with your implementation? Examples would be nice.

Comment: -1 http://www.emilvikstrom.se/whyidownvote.html (What is your question? What have you tried?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
if(root->right != NULL)
{
    return SearchValue(root->right, search_value);
}
if (root->left != NULL)
{
    return SearchValue(root->left, search_value);
}
return false;
```

to

```
if(root->right != NULL)
{
    if (SearchValue(root->right, search_value))
        return true;
}
if (root->left != NULL)
{
    if (SearchValue(root->left, search_value))
        return true;
}
return false;
```

The way you currently have it, it will always go down the right branch and return if it was found there, never checking the left branch.

Comment: This is O(n), kinda defeating the point of a binary tree, no?

Comment: @DeadMG: Not all binary trees are binary search trees. It doesn't look like a binary search tree (root's value is less than both its left and right value), so I've just solved the immediate problem he had. It actually looks like a binary min heap, so O(n) search would be correct.

Answer (score 5):

The current search will always follow the right branch if it exists (and then never follow the left branch).  If the data is ordered in the tree (which is typical), the code should examine the root node to make a decision on whether to traverse left or right.

Answer (score 0):

You can clearly tell that the code is wrong, because *you never perform a comparison*. Therefore, by default, the code cannot be correct.

You need to compare to decide which branch to go down, not simply test for existence.

Comment: I can't agree with you, the comparison is represented by the following fragment:
if(search_value != root->data)

Comment: @Sergey: That's not a `<` comparison. That only tells you if you're there- not what direction to go in.

Answer (score 0):

Just as Peter Alexander said, you cannot return on right-branch, the **only return condition** is equal and return true, for else condition, need continue left-branches.